# How to convert .ipa to .app file?

Tags: ios

everyone.
 I have some .ipa files and want to convert to archive file containing .app bundle. 
I tried to do this, but I have no way.
Is there any way to do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 34):

Rename the .ipa to .zip. Then just extract.

Answer (score 8):

Rename to zip. Then extract. Then find folder that say .app at end of folder name, then put all stuff in the folder in a zip, then rename the zip you made so that's it's .app instead of .zip

Answer (score 7):

1. Now you have the app setup file with .ipa extension.
2. Copy it to Desktop. You need to right-click on file and select Rename .ipa extension with .zip If you are given a warning, accept it to use .zip extension
3. Now click twice to unzip, Now go to Folder that you got after unzipping the file, and go inside Payload folder You will see .app file under Payload folder.
4. Right-click on .app file, and click Show Package Content.

Comment: But generated .app file not working on simulator

Answer (score 3):

Here are 3 simple steps

1.Change the extension from .ipa to .zip manually.

2.Double click on the .zip file to extract it.

3.The .app file will be present in the payload folder.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to convert an `ipa` to an `app`, e.g. from your CI/CD pipeline from the command line, so I have listed the commands needed to convert on the command line:

1. Locate and verify you have the `.ipa` file: `ls -alh YourApp.ipa`
2. Unzip it: `unzip YourApp.ipa`
3. Go to the `Payload` folder: `cd Payload`
4. Here is your `.app` folder: `ls Runner.app`, it will list a bunch of files
5. Optional: If someone asked for the `.app`, you might want to send it over email, upload it to a backend, in that case, you now need to "`zip` it back": `zip -r Runner.app.zip Runner.app`