# How do I install the XCUITest runner app and ipa on a real device and get the results?

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

How do I install the XCUITest runner app and ipa on a real device and get the results?

I have a runner.app that was generated by building it for testing, and a deployed/signed .ipa.

Now what I would like to happen is to have it installed on a real device, execute it, and get the device log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited with answer...

It *is* possible to achieve this. In order to build an ipa of the UI Testing app bundle you can follow these steps:

1. Open your project containing in Xcode.
2. Select the device you'd like to build the ipa for next to the scheme. This can be an actual device or a simulator.
3. Product > Build For > Testing
4. Find **[your_ui_test_bundle_name].app** file in Derived Data.

   - Derived data by default is located at **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**
   - To locate this file, dive into DerivedData for your project, navigating to **Build** > **Products** and then the respective directory based on what you chose in step 2. If you chose a simulator, look in ***-iphonesimulator/*** or if you chose a device look in **-iphoneos/**. The UI test bundle **.app** file should be in that directory.
5. Create a directory named **Payload** case sensitive and it *must* be named this.
6. Move the **.app** file into the **Payload** directory.
7. Compress the **Payload** directory.
8. Rename the compressed directory to have a file extension of .ipa. You'll be prompted and select *Keep .ipa*.

Now you have you UI test bundle application saved as an ipa. You can also upload this ipa to a device manually in Xcode via the following process (bonus info, yay!)

1. **Window** > **Devices and Simulators**
2. Select your connected device.
3. Tap the **+** button under *Installed Apps*.
4. Navigate to and select your UI test **.ipa** file that you compressed previously.
5. It should install onto the device.

Credit where it is due: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/how-to-run-your-iphone-test-on-aws-device-farm-98f18086811e

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the reason I'm asking is because I'm wondering if it would be possible to execute a test on a device w/o having the schema or the build. Let's say that I'll give it the files to a person and the person will execute it (runner and ipa). It's just like how external test services does it.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for clarifying your question Carlos. I've not heard nor read anything about this but I'm certainly curious now. I'll also play around a bit on my end and see if I can't come up with a solution. In the mean time, good luck!

Comment: Hi @atgrubb, I can't seem to find any information as well. any updates on your side?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta I've updated my answer and hopefully this works for you.

Comment: @atgrubb I don't understand how your answer relates to the question at hand. All you provided is how to create the ipa file.

Comment: @zwebie did you read the full answer? After explaining how to create the ipa i then provided 5 steps to take to install that ipa on the device...

Comment: @atgrubb yes, but the OP asked also how to execute the tests and get the logs, to which I don't see any reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bundleId :

```
let app = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "yourapp.bundle.id")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun somepath/YourAppName_iphoneos14.4-arm64.xctestrun -destination 'platform=iOS, id=some_id'
```

I moved `YourAppName_iphoneos14.4-arm64.xctestrun`, `YourAppName.app`,
`YourAppNameUITests-Runner.app` to some **local folder** from a regular `Library/Developer/etc..` build folder. Then I opened `*.xctestrun` file, which is an **xml** file, and **modified paths to my local folder** manually.

I couldn't find any official information about it but it seems like the `*.xctestrun` file is used by `xcodebuild` in order to find all relevant artefacts i.e both app folders. I would guess that's how they manage to run tests just with app's or ipa's without source code on various clouds...

PS. The question was about **IPA**, but it's convertible to the app, right? At least there is a thread - [How to convert .ipa to .app file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416660/how-to-convert-ipa-to-app-file/48079471)