# Programmatically touch iphone with coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift3

I am developing ios application which will listen to Some port where received data are coordinates of x,y to be touched,
In future i may need swipe and any UI function for My basic app, and then to any other app .
Reason: I just want to touch the acknowledge message of BT pairing for example .
Can any one tell me if this is feasible ? and a sample code with the used framework-library will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you want to "touch" a different app, or your own? If first, simply forget it.

Comment: Why to forget it ? yes i want to simply press on message box of BT connection security code for pairing, can you provide more details please ? because as i know, appium can press on coordinates for example .

Comment: If want write an app that sends touches to _any_ other app on a device -- not in an development environment but on "real" users device -- then you should just forget it. Even if it were technically possible (which it isn't), Apple would ban your app within an instant.

Comment: @Andreas Oetjen , Thanks alot for your help, but this is what Appium does, going to certain application, then go to home page and press on any thing you like. So can you tell me how to accept pairing bluetooth for example ?

Comment: Hi, you could take a look at the XCUITest framework, where you can manually code your UI Tests, perform taps etc. But I have no clue if and how to detect BT stuff here. But again: This runs as an automated test inside the development chain (Xcode etc.), not natively on the device.

Comment: I understand , that is really helpful , Appreciated, i will include XCUITest ,but question is can i compile those XCUITests into .ipa file , If so , can even it be in same .ipa file of my main application ? or this isn't possible ? because in that case , my application .ipa will do my main functionality beside touch on specific coordinates .

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801985/how-do-i-install-the-xcuitest-runner-app-and-ipa-on-a-real-device-and-get-the-re